# метод для отображения списка ресурсов (файлов)

Tags: c#, webbrowser

Есть ли в WebBrowser метод, которым можно отобразить при посещении вебстраницы список ресурсов (файлов), которые подгружаются вместе со страницей. JS, css... img
весь список файлов.

А то как-то писал под маки на Objective-C. Там Webkit. все четко и понятно. Гугл говорит: ищите какие-то сниферы трафика. Или сокеты собирайте, чтобы сеть всю слушать и фильтровать. В МСДн ничего особого не нашел среди методов.

Comment: вряд ли такое есть. или самому парсить загруженный хтмл или таки сокеты или использовать другой  движок, например awesomium

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 1):

Глубоко сомневаюсь, что данная задача имеет "красивое и элегантное" решение.

Дело в том, что в .NET стандартный WebBrowser это обёртка над обычным IE, причём сильно урезанная.

Поэтому, одно из двух:

- Использовать другой движок для работы с Web контентом;
- Использовать те же сокеты.

HTML парсить не советую потому, что ресурсы могут подгружаться не только с помощью соответствующих атрибутов и тэгов.  Это может быть реализовано также средствами CSS и JavaScript.

Comment: Да я так и понял что все урезанно/ Парить то понятно что это тупо и всех ресурсов несоберешь/ Какой то С# корявый/

Answer (score 1):

В WebBrowser есть события

- [WebBrowser.Navigating](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.windows.forms.webbrowser.navigating(v=vs.110).aspx)
- [WebBrowser.Navigated](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.windows.forms.webbrowser.navigated(v=vs.110).aspx)

Если их недостаточно по какой-то причине, то для перехвата трафика можно использовать [FiddlerCore](http://www.telerik.com/fiddler/fiddlercore). Скачайте [nuget-пакет](https://www.nuget.org/packages/FiddlerCore/) и подключите сборку к своему приложению.

Comment: Да я смотрел эти методы/ В них только увидел УРЛ по которому серфиш/  а где там ресурсы, файлы , размеры, размеры их, типы...

Comment: _"УРЛ по которому серфиш/ а где там ресурсы, файлы , размеры, размеры их, типы."_ -- это в FiddlerCore можно получить. или можно по url сделать запрос HEAD и сервер вернет только http-заголовок с размером файла, типом и т.д.